# What is a class that does encryption, decryption, hashing called?

Tags: security, terminology

I have a class that encrypts, decrypts, hashes and signs. In the future it may implement something else too, but my question is that what would that class be called. Currently I call it Encrypter, but it really does things that's not about encrypting. I have thought about the term Crypto, but I am not sure if that's what people usually use/think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it OpenSSL.  Hah,  no but seriously now `Crypto` is a good name for it i would also throw in a method to make a [Cryptographic Nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) and a String2Key function,  especially if you are using "passwords" for symmetric encryption.  I am glad you didn't call hashing a form of encryption,  because they are very different.

Comment: @rFactor Well passwords are usually human readable,  users repeat passwords and generally epically bad choice for use in encryption.  If you look at any professional encryption routines they use a s2k function which is usually (but not always) made from a message digest function that returns a base256 string (instead of the usual base16),   These functions can accept a password of any length and return a binary string of the exact length required for the encryption routine without the need for padding.

Comment: Ah, you are talking about Key Derivation Functions?

Comment: @rFactor also sometimes PBKDF2 is used as a s2k function as a method of key strengthening,  this is commonly found on encrypted file systems.

Comment: @rFactor a kdf is another name for it,  but s2k shows up a lot in RFC's so thats the word i like.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you might want to break up your single class into multiple classes, one for each major purpose:

- encrypting
- decrypting
- hashing
- signing
- signature verification

Then you can collect these classes into a library or module (terminology depends on what language you're using).

Comment: No, I really don't want to, because they do not consist of many lines of code and it feels like cluttering if I create a class of each.

Comment: Why?  hashing is a function that takes one argument.  Encryption is one function that takes 3-4 arguments.  Making a class out of such a simple method is gross.

Comment: Sure, making functions for each of these operations would be even better. But since the OP didn't actually say what language this is, maybe it's Java where you can't have anything *but* classes.

Answer (score 0):

Call it...
a **CrytoManager** or **CryptoService**?
or maybe...
 an EncryptionManager ?
or a CryptoUtility class ...